# Spivak Chapter 11, Question 34(b)

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is that prove that if $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$$ both exist, then $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0.$$

In this problem, I first suppose for contradiction that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ exists and it's not equal to $0$. Then I let $$l = \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x).$$
Then I consider two cases.
First, if $l > 0$, then according to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit as $x$ goes to infinity, $$l = \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$$ means that $\forall\epsilon > 0, \exists$ a number $N$ such that, $\forall x$, if $x>N$, then $|f'(x) - l| < \epsilon$. Then we can let $$\frac{l}{2} = \epsilon$$, thus we have $$|f'(x) - l| < \frac{l}{2}.$$ Then we get $$\frac{l}{2} < f'(x) < \frac{3l}{2}.$$ Then we have $$f(x) \ge f(N) + \frac{l}{2}(x-N)$$ for $x > N$. This means that $$|f(x) - f(N)| \ge \frac{l}{2}(x-N) > 0.$$ This means that the limit doesn't exist. However, I'm confused with the case when $l < 0$. I follow the definition and get $$\forall\epsilon > 0,\exists N$$ such that for all $x$, if $x>N$, then $$|f'(x) - l| < \epsilon.$$ And I let $$\frac{|l|}{2} = \epsilon.$$ And then I get $$\frac{-|l|}{2} < f'(x) - l < \frac{|l|}{2}.$$ Then I get $$\frac{l}{2} < f'(x) -l<\frac{-l}{2}.$$ Then I have $$\frac{3l}{2} < f'(x) < \frac{l}{2},$$ then I have $$f(x)\ge f(N) + \frac{3l}{2} (x-N),$$ for $x>N$. However $\frac{3l}{2}$ in this case is a negative number. Thus, I'm a little bit confused about how to lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Could you please state clearly the question? (and also add some space, it's really awful to read)

Comment: If you want some feedback, I suggest you mention the question you are trying to answer, and that you make your text more readable.

Comment: Thank you guys for reminding of my format! i just edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to change in the negative case is that when you look at the Mean Value Theorem you have
$$
|f(x)-f(N)|=|f'(\xi)|\,|x-N|\geq\frac{|l|}2\,|x-N|.
$$
Other than that, your argument is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Lef $\displaystyle \lim_{+\infty} f'(x) = \ell$.

1. If $\ell > 0$ then :
   $$\exists a > 0, \forall x \geq a, f'(x) \geq \dfrac{\ell}{2}$$
   Consider the function :
   $$g(x) = f(x) - \dfrac{\ell}{2} x$$
   We have :
   $$\forall x \geq a, g'(x) = f'(x) - \dfrac{\ell}{2} \geq 0$$
   then $g$ is increasing. We deduce that :
   $$\forall x \geq a, g(x) \geq g(a)$$
   then :
   $$\forall x \geq a, f(x) \geq \dfrac{\ell}{2} x + g(a) \underset{x \to +\infty}{\to} +\infty$$
   Contradiction with the fact that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ exists.
2. If $\ell < 0$ then consider the function $h = -f$ and we are in the first case.

we deduce that $\ell = 0$.